# Failed to load resource 405

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm a bit at a loss here.

I have a `thymeleaf` page and a `spring-boot` backend that takes in a `user` object, getting the object to the page is fine, my problem comes in when I'm trying to get it to the back end to do stuff with it.

I keep getting the following

```
2021-09-15 09:21:07.834  WARN 3624 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

and on the browser

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()`

for my controller I have the following

```
@Controller("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") final UserDto userDto) {
        //do stuff
        //userService.save(modelMapper.map(userDto, User.class));
        return "/user";
    }
}
```

as for my `thymeleaf` page

```
<form th:action="@{/user/add}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
                <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
                <input id="fullName" class="form-control form-group" type="text" th:field="*{fullName}">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" class="form-control form-group" type="email" th:field="*{email}">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" class="form-control form-group" type="password" th:field="*{password}">
                <p>
                    <button class="form-group form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                </p>
</form>
```

What am I missing here?

I did try to mess around the `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, `@RequestMapping(method = GET)`, `@RequestMapping(method = POST)`, `@RequestMapping(method = {GET, POST})`
I also tried `<form ... th:method="post">` and `<form ... th:method="get">`
But none of these seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add global `/user` in `@Controller`. this annotation is used to implement Web Application not for path and it is better to give global path in `application.properties` like below code. Inside `addUser()` method you want to return with page name like `return "user"` if go to the url then put `return "redirect:/user"`

Here down is modified code:

**application.properties**

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/user/
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") final UserDto userDto) {
        //do stuff
        //userService.save(modelMapper.map(userDto, User.class));
        return "pagename"; // enter page name where you wanna go not url
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<form th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
      <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
      <input id="fullName" class="form-control form-group" type="text" th:field="*{fullName}">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" class="form-control form-group" type="email" th:field="*{email}">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" class="form-control form-group" type="password" th:field="*{password}">
       <p>
          <button class="form-group form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
       </p>
</form>
```